# How to validate a Web App Apps Script url to watch Directory API changes

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to create an Apps Script to watch Directory changes.
I've found this answer : [Is it possible to watch Directory API changes from Google App Maker/Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51966939/is-it-possible-to-watch-directory-api-changes-from-google-app-maker-google-apps/51975881)
The Dimu Designs response Step2 don't work anymore, because "Publish > Register in Chrome Web Store" no longer exists in Apps Script Publish menu.
So, my question is : how to validate an Web App Apps Script url to watch Directory API changes?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, for me there is a bug as you can't perform the validation manually due to a mismatch with url in serach console, I opened a bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/147194530